# How to use Blob in flutter web application

Tags: javascript, flutter-web

I used FilePicker selected an image and want to convert it to Blob object on web, but the result is not right. Here is the code.

```dart
FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();
    if (result != null) {
      Uint8List? fileBytes = result.files.first.bytes;
      String fileName = result.files.first.name;
      debugPrint(fileName);

      if (fileBytes != null) {
        print(fileBytes.length);
        Blob blob = Blob(fileBytes, "text/plain", 'native');
        print(blob.size);
        await js.context.callMethod(
            'putObject', ["exampledir/exampleobject.png", blob, {}]);
      }
    } else {
      // User canceled the picker
    }
```

**blob.size** is not equal to **fileBytes.length** and it cannot be used on web.

**blob.size** should be **fileBytes.length**

Answer (score 1):

Tring a lot of times, it is simple to solve this problem.

just change

```dart
Blob blob = Blob(fileBytes, "text/plain", 'native');
```

to

```dart
html.Blob blob2 = html.Blob([fileBytes]);
```